# How to add Serial Number column in BIRT

Tags: java, birt

I want to add a serial number column in birt report.It should be reset based on grouping.How can i achieve this in BIRT?

Example:

```
| SerialNumber | Job Role | Employee       |
|              | role1    |                |
|       1      |          | Mickey Mouse   |
|       2      |          | Goofy          |
|       3      |          | Pluto          |
|              | role2    |                |
|       1      |          | Donald Duck    |
|              | role3    |                |
|       1      |          | Minnie Mouse   |
|       2      |          | Doctor Einmug  |
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit.I didn't get your point?

Comment: Serial number should reset based on grouping.

Comment: if we grouping employess based on job role,serial number should reset to 1 after every job role

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serial Number may be a confusing word...
I think you look for something like a Row Number that is reset to 1 for each group.

Try this:

- Add Aggregation

in the Aggregation Binding Builder use these values:

```
Column Binding Name:    SerialNumber
Data Type:              Float
Function:               RUNNINGSUM
Expression:             1
Aggregation On:         Group
```

Comment: instead of Aggregation Function `RUNNINGSUM` with Expression `1` you could also use the Aggregation Function `RUNNINGCOUNT` where the Expression gets irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I normally add an aggregation function with data type float and function running count for this kind of problem, just place the aggregate on group, so that the number will be reset on change of group.

Answer (score 1):

I can runningcount for me!!!
data type: integer
function: runningcount
expression: vars["no"]
aggregate on: group

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

1. If we need S.No Click on computed columns ---- >Click on New computed column Button ---- >
   Enter Column Name(S.No)--- >Select Data type--- >Select Aggregation In our Example Running Count -- ---- > OK